# Is there a cipher method that uses 9 digit(starts with 8,9 or else) and 10 digit(only starts with 1)

Tags: encryption, decode, decoder

1752462448 1933193007 1667526190 1684632419 1869767777 1886400099 1869426529 1953784163 1751999854 1953705777 808924214 943272760 825768241 858992688 876162865 808924214 959918133 892810033 825832761 808726350 1162236485 1412330081 1912602624 there is the cipher.

i tried dcode.fr Cipher Identifier and it says this is base36. yes i found something with it like a another cipher. i tried to decode it too but got nothing.

Comment: These are just 16-bit values, expressed as decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Example in Python for its universal intelligibility*:

```
c = '1752462448 1933193007 1667526190 1684632419 1869767777 1886400099 1869426529 1953784163 1751999854 1953705777 808924214 943272760 825768241 858992688 876162865 808924214 959918133 892810033 825832761 808726350 1162236485 1412330081 1912602624'
b = [bytes.fromhex(
        f'{int(a):08x}').decode() for a in c.split()]
print(''.join(b).rstrip('\x00'))
```

> https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1074689381891330049/1074697055731195904/NEFRET.rar

Note that  `b` is the following list (with the last element `'r\x00\x00\x00'`):

```
['http', 's://', 'cdn.', 'disc', 'orda', 'pp.c', 'om/a', 'ttac', 'hmen', 'ts/1', '0746', '8938', '1891', '3300', '49/1', '0746', '9705', '5731', '1959', '04/N', 'EFRE', 'T.ra', 'r\x00\x00\x00']
```

Therefore, wee need to remove all trailing `␀` (U+0000,  *Null*) characters (see `.rstrip('\x00')` in the last line of above code snippet).